# How can Alex Jones avoid paying the money he owes?

Tags: civil-judgment, enforcing-judgment

Alex Jones owes more than $1 billion dollars from the court cases he has lost.  As far as I know, he has yet to pay a cent.  From a legal perspective, how can he avoid paying any money at all for so long?

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons why an actual payment from a losing defendant may be delayed, including:

- orders to pay can be stayed (suspended) while being appealed, although the court will typically require the defendant to pay the money into court to be held in trust;
- the person owing can simply decline to pay (through a variety of avoidance tactics), leaving it to the plaintiff(s)/creditor(s) to commence enforcement actions like garnishment or seizure;
- a payment plan may have been agreed to, including a delay in the initial payment;
- the person owing might not have the funds — this circumstance would transition into bankruptcy proceedings with the successful plaintiffs among the creditors (I believe this is what's going on with Mr. Jones).

Comment: I don't believe Alex Jones has the orders stayed.

Comment: Two small additions: to stay a money judgment pending appeal you normally have to post a bond equal to the amount of the judgment although exceptions are made for very large judgments so that the full amount doesn't need to be posted; and the debt also dies with the debtor. Some states have a (long) statute of limitations to enforce a money judgment (in Colorado it is 20 years).

Comment: @ohwilleke Thank you. I added the first point, but I'm just checking how universal the second point is, so I can phrase it accurately. I think in many places, while debts are not inherited, debts are still payable out of the estate. Feel free to make an edit directly, too.

Comment: @Jen indeed. Debts are payable from the estate to the extent of its assets.